# Show Game Center startscreen

Tags: iphone, gamekit, game-center

I've started implementing Game Center into my game, and in all the tutorials I've followed they show how to open up the leaderboard-screen and the achievment-screen. Is there no startscreen in Game Center where you can access the achievments and leaderboard from? Because I don't want to have two buttons in my game in order to access them both.

To show leadearboards I use a GKLeaderboardViewController, and to show achievments I use a GKAchievementViewController. Is there another viewcontrollerin GameKit for the startscreen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there is no such screen. But you can implement it by your own if you really don't have the space or whatsoever for two buttons. Just another UIViewController subclass that gives the user the choice to show the leaderboards or achievements. But this is probably a waste of screen space (just two buttons), so the screen might look pretty empty. You should fill it with some other stuff (statistics or so).